# How to disable the "locate" command in Mac OS?

Tags: terminal, unix, services, daemons

According to this [article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/), I can use this command:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

To enable "locate" command to find files. However, recently I find this command not useful anymore and want to shutdown the background service/daemon. Does anyone have ideas about how to disable it or shutdown it? Thanks!

Comment: For people visiting in the future, title is misleading, User wants to disable the background service populating the `locate` command's database.  Not disable the `locate` command from running entirely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable it like this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Keep in mind, this process only runs periodically to make the database that caches the results, so your locate results will be static and not change from the time you unload the "refresh task".

Comment: Does that still work with SIP?

Comment: @JohnKeates If launchctl could be used to load locate by Firegun, why would unloading it fail?

Comment: Well, if you change something in a SIP location on a pre-SIP macOS version and then upgrade, it gets locked in place

Comment: Thanks! I'm using 10.13.3 and this command works for me.

Comment: even after unloading I am still able to use the "locate" command, why?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Unloading just stops the regular update of the database used by `locate`, it doesn't disable the command as such.

Comment: If you want to return `locate` to the state it was in when MacOS was installed, after unloading the launch daemon you can delete locate's database (usually `/var/db/locate.database`, but `locate -S` will tell you for certain). 

This prevents locate from continuing to work but returning stale results. Also, it will revert to displaying instructions on how to enable it should you want to reenable it in the future.